# Bootsrap col-md-3 GRID max-width pixel size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Anyone knows the max-width size of COL-MD-3 GRID in bootstrap 3?

I have an image thumbnail. I want to do is to get the max-width pixel size of the Col-md-3 grid.

I have a style div here I use

```
width:100%;
```

so it will fill the max-width of the col-md-3 but the problem is the

```
height:?;
```

because I want to copy the 100% width converted pixel so I will paste into height.

example: width:200px; height:200px; Like this but I can get what the max-width pixel size of col-md-3?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row" style="width:100%;       
                height:222px;
                background:#000 url('sample.jpg');
                background-attachment: scroll;
                background-position:center -10px;
                background-size:150% auto;
                background-repeat:no-repeat; ">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: you want to set a static height of maximum width of col-md-3 or you want height to be always equal to width. when viewport changes?

Comment: I want to know the max width pixel of the col-md-3 so I can set the height equal into the max width of col-md-3 :)

Comment: If its inside container + you are using default 12columns grid then (970px / 12) * 3

Comment: I used photoshop so I can see the max-width pixel of the col-md-3 the result is width = 263px but I'm not sure if it is the true pixel size..

Comment: ahh ok. yeah I used container. So the container is 970px and divide it to 12 hhmm Thanks for the help >_< :D I didn't notice lately haha

Comment: the result of my computing is 242.49